# How to deploy a Middleman site to GitHub user page

Tags: deployment, middleman, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy a Middleman project to my GitHub user page ([username].github.io). I'm using the [middleman-gh-pages](https://github.com/edgecase/middleman-gh-pages) gem, and the instructions seem simple enough.

However, after running `bundle exec rake publish`, my GitHub user page still shows a 404. I see the build on GH, and it's on the 'gh-pages' branch.

Here is my directory structure on master after publishing.

[image]

Here is my directory structure on the gh-pages branch after publishing.

[image]

When I navigate to [username].github.io/source/index.html.haml, my browser downloads the haml file. It seems like my gh-pages branch is not what's actually being served up. Has anyone else encountered this problem? How can I make it so the gh-pages branch is what is served when I go to my GitHub user page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `username.github.io` aka a **user/organisation** site is supposed to be pushed in `master` branch.

middleman-gh-pages gem seems to only push in `gh-pages` ([see publish task here](https://github.com/neo/middleman-gh-pages/blob/master/lib/middleman-gh-pages/tasks/gh-pages.rake)) which is the branch for **project** pages (`username.github.io/projectName`).

Comment: You're right. I'm circumventing the issue by writing a script that also pushes to master. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

i see this question is already resolved, but i'm still gonna put my two cents.

## How to deploy a Middleman project to Github Pages manually

Note: this guide describes how to deploy a project website, (e. g. `username.github.io/projectname`). If you're deploying a user website (e. g. `username.github.io`), you'll need to adjust some options. It's not hard to figure out!

### Project configuration

#### config.rb

Github Pages will serve your project website from a subfolder. This means that you can't reference your pages and assets with absolute URLs. Tell Middleman to use relative URLs:

```
activate :relative_assets
set :relative_links, true
```

Don't forget to use the [link_to helper](http://middlemanapp.com/basics/helpers/) for internal links, don't write `<a href...` manually.

#### .gitignore

Make sure that your `.gitignore` file lists the build folder. If it doesn't, add it:

```
/build/
```

#### .nojekyll

Github Pages use the Jekyll preprocessor that might interfere with your static website. To disable Jekyll magic, create a blank `.nojekyll` file under `source/`.

From your project root:

```
touch source/.nojekyll
```

### Repo preparation

You have to do this routine once.

1. Publish your project on Github.
2. Change into the `build/` directory. If you don't have it in your project, either create it manually or build your project with `bundle exec middleman build`.

   ```
   cd build/
   ```
3. Init an empty git repo:

   ```
   git init .
   ```
4. Add your Github repo as a remote:

   ```
   git remote add origin git@github...git
   ```
5. Start a new branch `gh-pages`:

   ```
   git checkout --orphan gh-pages
   ```

### Deployment routine

You'll have to repeat the following steps every time you deploy an update. Consider adding them to a batch file so that you don't have to repeat them manually.

1. Build your project.

   Starting at the project root:

   ```
   bundle exec middleman build
   ```
2. Change into the build directory:

   ```
   cd build/
   ```
3. Add all files:

   ```
   git add -A
   ```
4. Commit them. You don't really need a meaningful commit message here because your commit history is stored in your project's main branch. There's no big need to duplicate it here.

   ```
   git commit -m build
   ```
5. Push them to Github:

   ```
   git push origin gh-pages
   ```

   During the first push, add `-u`:

   ```
   git push -u origin gh-pages
   ```

---

Note that Github Pages take time for your website to show up. They say ten minutes but it might take hours. Be patient, though there's always a chance that you messed something up. :)

Subsequent pushes should be immediate. If a push is not reflected on you website, try bumping it with a subsequent push.

Comment: In your deployment routine I follow it when I want to redeploy. But now in my `gh-pages`-branch it committed `build/all-files`. But what is wanted is that it commits them directly and not in an extra `build`-folder. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You issued the commit command from your project root, but you had to do it from your build folder.